# Read user input txt file with a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, class, input

I have a data file that I need to extract data from. It has to be submitted via html input. I want to make a DataReader class to do so. The class needs to be constructed with the file and extract its attributes from the file, so

```
class DataReader() {
  constructor(file) {
     this.file = file;
  }
  extractData(){...}
}

var data = new DataReader(file);
console.log(data.attr0, data.attr1, data.attr3, ...);
```

I keep getting scope issues and I don't know how to make the class take a file when instantiated so it separates it's attributes.

This is what I have

```
class DataReader {
setFile(file) {
    this.file = file;
}

getFile() {
    return this.file;
}

extractData() {
    var self = this; // this == DataReader

    var objXMLhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    objXMLhttp.open("GET","diabetes400.txt",true);
    objXMLhttp.send();

    objXMLhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (objXMLhttp.readyState==4 && objXMLhttp.status==200) {
        var arrContents = objXMLhttp.responseText.split("\n"); // gotcha!
        self.setFile(arrContents);
        console.log(arrContents);
      }
        }

    }
}

var data = new DataReader();
data.extractData();
console.log(data.file);
```

If I log only data, i can see an object with file inside it, but file prints undefined

Comment: Could you elaborate on "scope issues"? Any error messages, or anything?

Comment: what does `file` look like ?

Comment: Where is that "data file"? On your web-server? On your local server? On your machine's file system? Somewhere else?

Comment: it's on my file system

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a FileReader.
Look at this project: http://bgrins.github.io/filereader.js/.
You can read a file an get the contents of it.

Look this example:

```
var inputUpload = document.getElementById('file-input');
FileReaderJS.setupInput(inputUpload , {
    on: {
       load: function(event, file){
            var textBase64 = event.srcElement.result
            var decodedText = atob(e.srcElement.result.split("base64,")[1]);
       }
    }
});
```